# What is wrong with "soma.jpeg" in Meteor All My Parties

Tags: meteor

I'm playing with the Meteor example "All My Parties". I wanted to substitute a screen shot of the map of my neighborhood for the supplied neighborhood.

First, I changed the css to a new png file of my own. It opened, but with a repeat of the image turning up. I added no-repeat to the css and then the image won't show up at all.

works:

```
background-image: url('/eugene.jpeg');
```

doesn't work:

```
background-image: url('/eugene.jpeg') no-repeat;
```

I tried opening the supplied "soma.jpeg" in Photoshop but got an invalid error. I ended up changing the suffix to png and that opened in Photoshop, then I resaved it, and renamed the suffix again.

Now I've got my neighborhood showing up . . . but can anybody tell me what's going wrong? First, why does their file have jpeg instead of jpg? Why won't that jpeg open in Photoshop? Why does a png not function correctly, as compared to the jpeg? Why did the addition of no-repeat make the image not load at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its just a .png file renamed to .jpeg which does not make any sense.
renaming the file and changing the css to:
    background-image: url('/soma.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
works fine for me.

.jpeg and .jpg refers to the same filetype. The .jpg suffix was probably established because older operating systems only allowed 3 character suffixes.

Comment: Hmmm. Weird. I'm still having trouble with it as a png.

Comment: Thanks, you're right... and I just [fixed it in Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/1070a682fd651ffd35a13b8193de899c8ec61f1b)! Feel free to open issues or file pull requests when you notice things like this in the future.